# REST API - как передавать параметры

Tags: java, rest, веб-служба

Я программирую на JAVA. Я знаю 2 подхода передачи параметров в запросе:

- PathParam
- RequestParam

Я читал, что соглашением архитектурного стиля RESTFull, описывающего правила проектирования веб-сервисов, является использование переменных в пути URL, согласно которому идет обращение к сервису..
 То есть я предполагаю, что те кто строит свои приложения согласно RESTFull, должны использовать PathVariable для передачи параметра в запросе

Так ли это ?

Если применяется **RequestParam**, тогда это уже не является чистым RESTFull ?
 Я предпочитаю использовать только **PathVariable**, - и считаю что не стоить использовать передачу параметров в URI-запроса...

Хотя согласно соглашению REST, мы для извлечения данных, должны использовать GET-запрос.
 А если запрос сложный, то мы можем спроектировать приложение так, чтобы наше REST api принимало несложные запросы....

Или же кто-то использует другой подход и любит использовать **get**-запрос с множеством параметров?
 Если это так, просьба аргументировать и как вы считаете, правильно ли строить **Enterpise application**, таким образом ?

Но ведь в данном случае, если мы используем технологию REST, то согласно ее правилам, GET запрос используемый для излечения данных, не должен содержать параметров или нет ?

Может кто грамотно разъяснить эти моменты ?

Answer (score 4):

`RequestParam` использовать абсолютно нормально. В случае GET-запроса, `PathVariable` - идентификация ресурса, `RequestParam` - дополнительные условия выборки (условия фильтрации/паджинации).

Например:

GET `/users` - получить всех пользователей

Такой же запрос с паджинацией, чтобы не отдавать клиенту все:

GET `/users?page=1&size=2`

С фильтром:

GET `/users?sex=male` - получить всех пользователей определенного пола

Далее с `PathVariable`:

GET `/users/1/books?author=2` - Получить все книги автора `2` у пользователя с идентификатором `1`