Как лучше передавать параметры в REST API?
В REST API можно организовать параметры как минимум двумя способами:

Как часть URL-пути через аргументыˆ /api/resource/parametervalue
В качестве аргумента запроса, query parameters: /api/resource?parameter=value

Вопросы:

Какие задачи лучше решать каким способом?
Существуют ли способы параметризации API, которые я забыл?


Не дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085276

Более интересен вопрос: зачем ввели два разных синтаксиса для одного и того же?

Семантически они играют разные роли, но как костыли могут решать одинаковые ситуации )

в чём разница их ролей?

@ESkri первый вариант это части пути, т.е. семантически обращение к статитчески существующим "секциям" (условно, как в языках вызов метода myObject.Foo.Things.Sort). Второй вариант это аргументы, т.е. семантически динамические/вычисляемые модификаторы (условно, как в языках аргументы вызова метода Sort(sortAsc, ignoreCase, dontCache)). Соответственно, никто не запретит например писать метод SortAscIgnoreCaseDontCache(), но лучше так не делать :-)

Существуют ли способы параметризации API, которые я забыл? - ну да, передавать все параметры в теле запроса в виде json. В максимальном виде это может быть GraphQL, например.

@Kromster - вы описали разницу в их синтаксисе, а не семантике.  или вы хотели сказать, что /api/resource/parametervalue существует на сервере в виде отдельного статического файла для каждого значения parametervalue?  вопрос "зачем оно надо" так и остался не раскрыт.

@ESkri Я как раз таки попытался пояснить семантику (смысл) на примерах. (и специально написал "секцию", а не файл, т.к. способ хранения не относится к делу). Оно "так надо" для уже указанного выше - чтобы разделять то что точно существует как сущность и действие, от аргументов/параметров. Где и как провести эту границу - каждый автор АПИ решает сам (/api/resource/parametervalue или /api/resource?parameter=value).

@Kromster - то есть, этот синтаксис сделали, чтобы выделить обязательные параметры запроса?  а для кого это нужно?  1. серверу? парсеру на сервере всё равно какой синтаксис парсить.  2. разработчику скрипта, отправляющего запрос?  у него мануал с описанием всех операций и всех параметров.  3.  промежуточному кэширующему серверу?  им тоже пофиг, они всю строку запоминают.  4. админу, читающему логи сервера?  типа, чтобы главный параметр запроса стоял на "первом" месте?  короче, я теряюсь в догадках - в чём профит и для кого?

@ESkri почти весь синтаксис (в широком смысле) придуман для контроля "сложности" написания софта человеками. Компилятору совершенно все равно как названы объекты и методы. Ассемблеру совершенно все равно что там за типы данных и переменные. Транзисторам совершенно все равно какие инструкции или данные "выполнять".

@Kromster - вам запись /api/user/{id}/orders кажется менее "сложной" чем /api/orders?userid={id}?  в чём профит-то?  кстати, а как независимые сборщики статистики (кибана и т.п.) смогут догадаться, как по URL определить эндпоинт, чтобы правильно собрать статистику по эндпоинтам?  раньше всё было просто: до знака вопроса - эндпоинт, после - его параметры

@ESkri подумайте сами, чем отличаются две эти формы записи. Почему вообще они записаны так, а не orderofpetrovich или api/system/product/catalog/local/list/book/main/userorderid. В вашем примере, профит может быть в семантике (смысле). В первом случае API демонстрирует, что user это самостоятельная сущность со своими заказами, а во втором случае, что есть список заказов из которого можно отфильтровать например по userId. И тот и другой вариант имеют право на жизнь, оба примерно одинаково "сложны", но несут слегка разный смысл.

"чтобы правильно собрать статистику по эндпоинтам?" - обычно перед разработчиками API такая задача либо ставится, либо (чаще) - нет. Если задачи нет, то и предпринимать какие-то усилия для того чтобы сделать удобно парсерам смысла/времени/сил нету. Также вспомним ЧПУ.

В первом случае API демонстрирует, что user это самостоятельная сущность со своими заказами, а во втором случае, что есть список заказов из которого можно отфильтровать например по userId - не вижу разницы.  если вы её "видите", то замените слово "user" на слово "дата" в вашем предложении - ваша фраза останется настолько же верна.  ок, я понял, что объяснить простыми словами вы не можете.  видимо, обсуждаемый предмет является объектом понтов/веры, а не инструментом для удобства/профита.  говоря языком разработчиков, это свистелка-перделка.

@ESkri давайте попробуем попроще, представьте автослесаря. Его просят проверить гайки на определенном колесе (car/wheel/{id}/bolts) из чего мы можем сделать вывод, что колесо это отдельная штука и у него будут еще другие методы и параметры. Или же просят проверить состояние гаек, которые относятся к колесу car/bolts/?wheel={id} из чего можно заключить, что эта машина скорее "ведро с маркированными болтами" )). Другими словами, в первом случае идет группировка по системам и эти системы структурированы по мотивам ООП, а во втором - все в однородной коллекции и обращение идет по свойствам.

Насчет даты - ничего не меняется. В некоторых системах дата это сущность, а в некоторых - лишь фильтр.

@Kromster - ну, фиксированная иерархия существует только в простых системах, где очень мало типов сущностей.  в любой реальной системе будет что-то вроде OLAP-куба из десятков атрибутов, где очень сложно сказать, что один атрибут (клиент, дата, канал продаж, тип продукции, локация,...) будет "главнее" другого и поэтому должен стоять выше по ООП-иерархии.

@ESkri зависит от системы обычно. Какие-то системы проще разложить в ООП-иерархию, какие-то сложнее (пример - где-то уместен SQL, где-то NoSQL). Мне кажется я понял в чем может быть сложность с пониманием разницы - я с самого начала говорю о разных системах, спроектированных изначально в разном стиле для разных предметных областей, а вы, кажется, проецируете все на одну систему к которой просто по-разному строите запросы.

@Kromster - я с самого начала говорю о разных системах - о каких таких разных? )))  в мире есть только одна полезная иерархическая система - это стандартный GUI - рисование вложенных окон/контролов на прямоугольном экране.  все остальные реальные системы, с которыми приходится работать, не имеют однозначной иерархии.  вы только сейчас узнали, что ООП - это игрушка, не применимая в реальной жизни?

@ESkri выше вы приводили в пример что-то похожее на складскую систему ("клиент, дата, канал продаж, тип продукции, локация"), где на ваш взгляд удобнее OLAP-куб. Есть другие системы, где удобнее иерархия. GUI (не совсем понятно при чем он тут) это обычно просто динамическое дерево, но если попробовать представить к нему API то можно достаточно быстро заметить разницу в удобстве между перечисленными выше подходами ;-)

@Kromster - Есть другие системы, где удобнее иерархия - примеры - в студию!  наверняка это будут очень упрощённые системы.

@ESkri можете посмотреть FHIR (https://www.hl7.org/fhir/overview.html), там и сущностей и параметров достаточно много.

Можете еще посмотреть онлайн-справки сложных систем в целом, типа Microsoft или ЯП. Они обычно достаточно подробно отражают нижелещие модели в виде иерархий.

Первый пример /api/resource/parametervalue используется когда вам параметр нужен как часть пути или привязки к чему-то. На пример возьмём контроллер для работы с материалами, и какие у него могут быть допустимые адреса:

api/material/create
api/material/get/all?name=p_name&price=123
api/material/get/{id}
api/material/{id}/update/name
api/material/{id}/update/description
api/material/{id}/update/price
api/material/{id}/delete
api/material/{id}/attach
api/material/{id}/detach

В чём суть? Когда вы используете параметр id, вы уточняете, для кого вы хотите выполнить то или иное действие. Так же, второй пример содержит query parameters, т.е. те, которые идут после амперсанда. Это значит, это они не обязательные. К пример, вы можете использовать их как часть фильтров для get запросов.
Для post запросов они в основном не используются или, по крайней мере, я не видел таких вариантов применения. Почему? Потому что параметры строки запроса передают некие данные на сервер. При выполнении post запроса вы и так передаёте данные, но уже в теле запроса. Да, для post запроса так же используются параметры маршрутизации (id в этом и подобных примерах api/material/{id}/detach), но вы так же можете их передавать просто в теле запроса, но это уже будет немного не по конвенциям REST Api.
Напомню, что основная разница между get и post запросом в том, что get запрос не может иметь тела запроса. Параметры запроса решают проблемы уточнения данных, которые вы хотите получить, соответственно, они не используются для post запросов.
В заключение, параметры запроса и параметры маршрутизации это разные вещи, которые делают примерно одно и то самое - передаю данные. Параметры маршрутизации используются для уточнения пути к объекту, с которым вы собираетесь работать, а параметры запроса используются больше как фильтры при неком запросе и являются не обязательными.
UPD: Что имеет смысл использовать при put, patch и delete запросах? Есть разобраться, то put запрос это как смесь между get и post и в основном предназначен для идентификации сервером намерений клиента, т.е., обновление неких данных. Есть ли смысл использовать тут параметры запроса? Думают нет, поскольку вам нужно просто передать данные для обновления в теле запроса и идентификатор объекта, которых хотите обновлять, а его, как было написано ранее, можно передать как параметр маршрутизации или так самое в теле запроса.
patch использует для обновления специальные инструкции, по этому тут так же не стоит ничего лишний раз придумывать.
delete не передаёт никакое тело, а должен передать только идентификатор объекта, которые стоит удалить. Ситуация аналогичная, вы можете это сделать используя параметр маршрутизации. Почему именно его? Поскольку эти данные обязательные.
